# backbone.js updating a model whose attributes have been changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In SQL you would use the UPDATE command to update a row, how do you update a model in SQL where it's attributes have been changed from say another JSON Object.

I would like to do this in such a way so that it only changes the attributes that have been changed and not the whole model, I have seen the model.changedAttributes() command, but not sure how to use this.

Thanks

Edit:

I have tried this:

```
//code to update model
usersCollection.fetch({
  success: function() {
    var getModel = usersCollection.where(checkIDJSON);
    //update that partcular attribute
    getModel.set('interest', 'rolling stones');
    console.log("Users:" + usersCollection.toJSON());
  }, error: function() {
    // something is wrong..
  }                     
});
```

It returns with an error, "undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to save data from the model to the server with RESTful service and don't want to send all the data of the model but only those attributes which have been changed only. For this purpose you should use `patch` method:

```
model.save(attrs, {patch: true})
```

You may send only `attrs` in this case or

```
model.save({patch: true})
```

just attributes which have been changed (in this case `attrs` will be `model.changedAttributes()`)

From backbone documentation:

If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call `model.save(attrs, {patch: true})`. You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes.

Comment: I have an existing model saved locally (local sql db); I would just like to update the attributes which have been changed. Will this method work with it?

Comment: It depends on your `Backbone.sync` method. I mean that if you use local sql db without restful api then you use some plugin for backbone which override method sync.

Comment: I have updated my original question with code. I am just setting one attribute,but in future I would like to pass in a whole JSON array

Comment: I have got it to work, had to fetch collection with all of its models, then wrap a for each to go through each model and set , save attributes that way

Comment: If you got it to work then you should post your solution so others in the future can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this right now myself.

Your logic looks correct from the documentation. After your `getModel.set('interest', 'rolling stones');` I would do

```
getModel.save(); //saves the model to the database (or whatever you have setup)
userCollection.reset(); // reloads the collection from the database (or whatever you have setup.
```

If are not using the Backbone.sync methods then in order for backbone to work well I'd recommend overriding these methods in your classes.